# Save selected date and not utc date in react redux

Tags: typescript, react-redux, utc, react-datepicker

I tried following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253688/format-date-in-redux-reducer-before-it-hits-state) and find a solution with the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50789122/react-redux-not-saving-in-state-as-intended).

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253688/format-date-in-redux-reducer-before-it-hits-state/37255075) had a part of the information that I need but it did not provide me with an answer. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945003/format-date-as-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-sssz) almost had what I wanted but redux does not let me pass the output date in the state.

I am writing a react application using redux (typescript v. ^3.8) and have a dateTimePicker component that uses the "react-datepicker" npm package version : v.2.15. I select a value from the picker let's say 07/07/2020, but when I save it in a state with a reducer,

the action.payload is of type **Tue Jul 07 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)**

but inside the state I now have **2020-07-06T21:00:00.000Z**.

My understanding is the property that the date is being saved, is of type date but the format "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ" is an ISOstring() in utc.

How can I pass only the selected value (07/07/2020) in the state, without taking into account local/utc date and timezone? I am aiming to have just this **2020-07-07T00:00:00.000Z**

In my reducer how should I manipulate the date to have the above result? My code snippet is this:

```
export const changeGeneralFormDateReducer = (
  state: IState,
  action: IAction<Date>
): IState =>
  produce(state, (draftState: IState) => {   
    draftState.generalForm.Date = action.payload;    
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use something like this

```
draftState.generalForm.Date = new Date(
    Date.UTC(
      action.payload.getFullYear(),
      action.payload.getMonth(),
      action.payload.getDate()
    )
  );
```

Comment: This is helpful, however can you state a reason or solution since changing all dates across huge applications is not easy.